# Div show under another div

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs, the map, the contact info and the content div. I want to change the map and the contact info as it can be seen here:

http://budapestflats.hu/single.php?id=3

My problem is that the contact info div is not getting under the content div, because it can still be seen.

Can you provide me with a CSS trick with which I could hide the contact info div under the content div?

Comment: Provide the code that you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the z-index css properties on the divs. A higher z-index number means the div will be on top of those with lower z-indexes.

```
.map{
    z-index: 1;
}
.contact {
    z-index: 2;
}
.content{
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem was with these z-indexes.